# Resizing Epiphany browser (Webbrowser) in Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, kiosk

I have been searching in google since one day and I have not found any information of how to resize the webbrowser window (for example, half of the screen) just starting the raspberry pi.

At the moment I achieved starting the webbrowser in kiosk with this code:

In `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@epiphany-browser http://www.google.de
```

Any idea of how can give/configure a given size to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by my own.

Just creating a script and using `wmctrl` in the script.
When starting the PC it run automatically this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
epiphany http://www.google.de &
sleep 15s
epiphany --new-window www.wikipedia.com & 
sleep 15s
SOURCE=/usr/bin
echo "$SOURCE"
$SOURCE/wmctrl -r wikipedia -e 0,0,0,800,1080
$SOURCE/wmctrl -r Google -e 0,800,0,1120,1080
```